# Determine which program is listening to a port, when it's the System process (PID: 4)?

Tags: windows, port, windows-10

My software application runs on port 5700. In the past few days with the recent Windows updates, some of my users' software has stopped working due to this port now being in use by the System process (PID: 4).

I am not sure how to determine which program is using this port?  Either it's being used by Windows itself (which would be odd, for the System process to just start using a new port), or some other program is using the System process as some sort of proxy.

For example, I've seen that when I listen to some ports for HTTP requests in my app, then the PID that is shown using that port number is 4 (System process).  This is more or less confirmed here: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/428

I have tried running the command `netsh http show urlacl` to see all of the HTTP port reservations, but my port doesn't show up in this list.  So it doesn't appear to be reserved, but it's *in use*.

The exception in question when we try listening on that port is:

> A TCP error (10013: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way
>   forbidden by its access permissions) occurred while listening on IP
>   Endpoint=0.0.0.0:5700.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Procexplorer, netstat, tasklist, etc... tend to be shy on details as System obfuscates underlying info.

You could try `net stop http` to deload HTTP.sys. it should warn you what services have a dependency on it. Use that output to go through a process of elimination... hopefully you find the culprit.

As a side note, I know Dell SupportAssist uses port 5700, but that shouldn't run as System.

Comment: FYI: I just looked at one of my home laptops and Dell Support Assist does in fact run as System.

Comment: Interesting, mine is wrapped in its own daemon for the service. All of my instances are new though, so maybe a version difference? Good to know though

Comment: My bad, I just looked again after updating SupportAssist and it's running under the user context of the logged in user that launches it. Apologies.

Comment: Bingo, it was Dell Support Assist.

Answer (score 1):

I would try running [tcpview](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/tcpview.aspx) from SysInternals, it has always helped in scenarios like this.

Comment: I used TCPView, it doesn't really give any more information other than the fact that the System process is listening on port 5700.  Is there something specific you had in mind?

Comment: Have you tried changing startups to minimal set, then adding things back in?